# Parsing an HTML table in Android studio

Tags: java, android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to process a large amount of data for a research project. I have one html file loaded trough Jsoup, but the problem is that the table I need to evaluate does not have an Id or CLASS. I have searched stack, but I don't seem to find an answer as to how I can reach each `<tr>` and get the information out of its `<td>`'s.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">inf1</td>
        <td align="center">date</td>
        <tdalign="center">time</td>
        <td align="center">group</td>
        <td  align="center">name</td>
        <td align="center">---</td>
        <td align="center">room</td>
        <td align="center">---</td>
        <td align="center">---</td>
        <td> </td>
        <tdalign="center">reason</td>
        <td align="center"> </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

(The empty `<td>`'s and the `"---"` are just for displaying purposes in this table and don't have any value for my project)

I need to sort each `<tr>` (structured in the same way) by group and inf1 with the other data linked to them in order to use the data in an android Studio project where they will be displayed differently.

Thank you in advance for help:)

Comment: Is the table structure fixed? I mean is the inf1 `td` always the 1st and group always the 4th?

Comment: yes the structure is fixed they are always in the same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jsoup CSS selectors and a custom class that implements Comparable to keep the records. Something like this:

```
String html = ""
        +"<table>"
        +"    <tr>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">inf1</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">date</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">time</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">group1</td>"
        +"    </tr> "
        +"</table>"
        +"<table>"
        +"    <tr>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">inf1</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">date</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">time</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">group0</td>"
        +"    </tr> "
        +"</table>"
        +"<table>"
        +"    <tr>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">inf2</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">date</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">time</td>"
        +"        <td align=\"center\">group0</td>"
        +"    </tr> "
        +"</table>"
        ;

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
class TableRecord implements Comparable<TableRecord>{
    public String inf = "";
    public String grp = "";

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TableRecord arg0) {
        int cmpGrp = arg0.grp.compareTo(this.grp);
        if (cmpGrp==0){
            return arg0.inf.compareTo(this.inf);
        }
        return cmpGrp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "grp="+grp+":inf="+inf;
    }
}
List<TableRecord> tableRecords = new ArrayList<>();
Elements trs = doc.select("table tr");
for (Element tr : trs){
    Elements tds = tr.select("td");
    TableRecord tableRecord = new TableRecord();
    tableRecord.inf = tds.get(0).text();
    tableRecord.grp = tds.get(3).text();

    tableRecords.add(tableRecord);
}

Collections.sort(tableRecords);
for (TableRecord tableRecord:tableRecords){
    System.out.println(tableRecord);
}
```